# Why does NMaximize show errors for the same code FindMaximum gives solution? The errors need not corresond to local vs. global solution aspect

Tags: mathematical-optimization

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
A[a_, b_, c_] := {{a, b}, {b, c}};

eigsys[a_, b_, c_] := Eigensystem[A[a, b, c]];
evals[a_, b_, c_] := eigsys[a, b, c][[1]]; 
evect[a_, b_, c_] := eigsys[a, b, c][[2]];
order[a_, b_, c_] := Flatten[Map[Position[Sort[evals[a, b, c]], #] &, evals[a, b, c]]];

evalues[a_, b_, c_] := evals[a, b, c][[order[a, b, c]]];
evectors[a_, _, c_] :=   evect[a, b, c][[order[a, b, c]]];

m1[a_, b_, c_] := evalues[a, b, c][[1]];
m2[a_, b_, c_] := evalues[a, b, c][[2]];

m[a_, b_, c_] := m2[a, b, c]^2 - m1[a, b, c]^2;

ssq12[a_, b_, c_] := (evectors[a, b, c]^2)[[2, 1]];


sol = NMaximize[{m1[a, b, c],
   6.82*10^-5 <= m[a, b, c] <= 8.04*10^-5 
    && m1[a, b, c] > 0 
    && m1[a, b, c] + m2[a, b, c] <= 0.11
    && 0.269 <= ssq12[a, b, c] <= 0.343 
          }, {a, b, c}]
```

This code is giving errors like `The following constraints are not valid` and `Constraints should be equalities, inequalities, or domain specifications involving the variables.`
But the same code is giving result with `FindMaximum`. But I want to find a global maximum
to the problem. Is something wrong with the `SetDelayed`? With or without `SetDelayed` `FindMaximum` is working but in both the cases `NMaximize` isn't working. Also I believe that the problem has a global maximum which differs from the local maximum.

If I seed one of the variables with an initial value the error message changes to `Variables {{a,0.1}, b, c} should be a list of variables, with each element being a variable, or a list containing a variable and lower and upper bounds for the starting region for that variable.`

P.S.: The command with `Flatten...` is to sort eigenvalues in the ascending order and get the corresponding eigenvectors to define the `ssq12`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a number of conditions on parameters, with NMaximize you can never be safe to get the global maximum. Try to use Maximize, where possible, like in this case, where there are quasilinear equations and conditons.

It often helps to give explicit statement, that square roots are greaterequal zero (here d). Since b is not used in maximization function, things get simple to substitute d and eliminate b.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
A[a_, b_, c_] := {{a, b}, {b, c}};    
eigsys[a_, b_, c_] := Eigensystem[A[a, b, c]];
evals[a_, b_, c_] := eigsys[a, b, c][[1]];
evect[a_, b_, c_] := eigsys[a, b, c][[2]];
order[a_, b_, c_] := 
  Flatten[Map[Position[Sort[evals[a, b, c]], #] &, evals[a, b, c]]];    
evalues[a_, b_, c_] := evals[a, b, c][[order[a, b, c]]];
evectors[a_, _, c_] := evect[a, b, c][[order[a, b, c]]];    
m1[a_, b_, c_] := evalues[a, b, c][[1]];
m2[a_, b_, c_] := evalues[a, b, c][[2]];    
m[a_, b_, c_] := m2[a, b, c]^2 - m1[a, b, c]^2;    
ssq12[a_, b_, c_] := (evectors[a, b, c]^2)[[2, 1]]

srule = Sqrt[a^2 + 4 b^2 - 2 a c + c^2] -> d

eqd = d == Sqrt[a^2 + 4 b^2 - 2 a c + c^2]

condd = d >= 0

cond0 = 6.82*10^-5 <= m[a, b, c] <= 8.04*10^-5 /. srule // 
  Rationalize[#, 0] &

cond1 = m1[a, b, c] > 0 /. srule

cond2 = m1[a, b, c] + m2[a, b, c] <= 0.11 /. srule // 
  Rationalize[#, 0] &

cond3 = 0.269 <= ssq12[a, b, c] <= 0.343 /. srule // 
  Rationalize[#, 0] &

redd = Reduce[{cond0, cond1, cond2, cond3, eqd, condd}, {a, c, 
   d}, {b}]

(max = Maximize[{1/2 (a + c - d), redd}, {a, c, d}]) // AbsoluteTiming

(*   {36.0400310, {5469/100000, 
{a -> 7366133/134300000, 
 c -> 7406867/134300000, 
 d -> 31/50000}}}   *)

max // N
```

It's easy to get b from a,c,d, if you need.